# Log file for ArcGIS geoprocessing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, arcgis-9.3

Whenever I run a geoprocess overnight, it seems my computer reboots. Does ArcGIS save some log file information? Where does it save it?

For example, when I run a large dataset or image process I need to perform overnight, does it save the logfile that tells you what it performs from start to finish?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have logging turned on, you will be able to see your geoprocessing results in a log file. The "Log geoprocessing operations to a log file" option (under Geoprocessing [menu] -> Geoprocessing Options... in ArcGIS 10 or under Tools [menu] -> Options -> Geoprocessing [tab] in ArcGIS 9.3) will do what you're looking for.

Default locations for these files are `C:\Documents and Settings\<user name>\Application Data\ESRI\ArcToolbox\History` in Windows XP and `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\(Local or LocalLow or Roaming)\ESRI\ArcToolbox\History` in Vista (and presumably 7).

More details from Esri [here](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/keeping_track_of_geoprocessing_history/history_log_files.htm).

Comment: hello, what's the file location for a Windows Server 2008?

Comment: `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.3\ArcToolbox\History` on Windows Server 2012 with Desktop 10.3.

Answer (score 5):

You can also review the process by looking at the geoprocessing results window.
As mentioned by nmpeterson, go to the Geoprocessing menu, but then go to --> Results --> Current Session.  Expand the Messages option to review the actions and processes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just noticed that you've used the tag for arcgis-9.3.1.  The Geoprocessing menu and results option is available in 10.0.  :(

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I like to look at the ArcToolbox History folder. It is a more complete picture of what you are doing - ie it will show you all the inputs and outputs for building a Service Definition file not just GP tools used.

`C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop[VERSION#]\ArcToolbox\History`