# Exporting geoprocessing results history from MXD?

Tags: geoprocessing, arcgis-10.4, mxd, results-window

I have an MXD with the results saved to it. 
I want to look at the parameters that were set for some of the tools externally, so I want to export the results.

Can this be done?

[image]

Comment: I don't think it can be done retroactively, for processing you've already completed, but if you have geoprocessing logging turned on it's saved: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16899/log-file-for-arcgis-geoprocessing

Comment: @DanC Thanks, alas this is not an option for me as i don't have the computer that ran these tools and saved this mxd.

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to have the geoprocessing details saved is to  turn logging on, but even then they're saved on the PC that did the processing, in the user folder of the user who did the processing, and not in the MXD. I think the only way to get them out of an MXD is by copying and pasting them individually.

Comment: Have you seen right click save as result file? You can open a result file back into arc map and open it from the results window.   Does that do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

In the catalog window you could do a right click on the layer you want to review and access the metadata, there is an geoprocessing history section with detail (date and time, tool used and parameters) you could export to XML or copy/paste.

More detail on that and on how to view [tool execution history](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/history-log-files.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the tools you want to save and then either save them as Python snippets and paste them into a text file or select save as and save them as a results file.  Or like KHibma says - if you save individual tools as a results file you can use ArcCatalog to add them back into ArcToolbox and see the parameters.